# Recommendations for a Lua IDE on Windows

Tags: lua, ide

I'm looking for a good Lua IDE or Lua Plugin to work with.

I've tried the following IDE's and Plugins:

- Eclipse Plugin (all 3)
- IDEA Plugin (lags like hell when editing Classes with more than 5k lines of code)
- VS 2013 Plugin (doesn't display all files in the project solution explorer, just lua files.) (We are working with all kinds of files. HTML, XML, JSON, INI, LUA)
- SciTE, gVim, Atom, luaEdit

It would be nice to see an auto-completion and / or metatable support. (Auto completion, class explorer)

Greetings

Comment: [lua-users LuaEditorSupport](http://lua-users.org/wiki/LuaEditorSupport) is the place for that.

Answer (score 2):

There used to be a closed question about Lua IDE, which was quite useful in my opinion; there is also a [related SO question for Lua IDE on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4808361/recommendations-for-a-lua-ide-and-debugger-on-windows). I can suggest to try [ZeroBrane Studio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ZeroBrane_Studio), but I'm biased being the author.

Answer (score 0):

For now, the best plugin for developing Lua codes might be Emmylua, a plugin in IntelliJ Idea. But it has not yet caught up with the newest Idea version, so be sure to install older versions.